# XML in SSRS Dig below Metadata

Tags: xml, web-services, reporting-services

I call a Webservice with my SSRS report and normally have no trouble setting up my SOAP Action, my method, setting up a parameter and using an Element Path however, this time I am stumped. The webservice responds in this fashion to the UI Developer:

```
Response

<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header />
  <s:Body>
    <GetStatusForPreRequestChangeDTResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <GetStatusForPreRequestChangeDTResult>
        <xs:schema id="PreRequestChangeStatus" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
          <xs:element name="PreRequestChangeStatus" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:element name="PreRequestChangeStatus">
                  <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                      <xs:element name="company" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                      <xs:element name="version" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                      <xs:element name="changeID" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                      <xs:element name="stageID" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                      <xs:element name="status" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                      <xs:element name="stepID" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                      <xs:element name="stepStatus" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                      <xs:element name="background-color" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                      <xs:element name="border-color" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                      <xs:element name="color" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                    </xs:sequence>
                  </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
              </xs:choice>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
        </xs:schema>
        <diffgr:diffgram xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
          <PreRequestChangeStatus xmlns="">
            <PreRequestChangeStatus diffgr:id="PreRequestChangeStatus1" msdata:rowOrder="0" diffgr:hasChanges="inserted">
              <company>1</company>
              <version>1</version>
              <changeID>208</changeID>
              <stageID>2</stageID>
              <status>late</status>
              <stepID>4</stepID>
              <stepStatus>off</stepStatus>
              <background-color>#bbbbbb</background-color>
              <border-color>#888888</border-color>
              <color>#222222</color>
            </PreRequestChangeStatus>
            <PreRequestChangeStatus diffgr:id="PreRequestChangeStatus2" msdata:rowOrder="1" diffgr:hasChanges="inserted">
              <company>1</company>
              <version>1</version>
              <changeID>208</changeID>
              <stageID>2</stageID>
              <status>late</status>
              <stepID>5</stepID>
              <stepStatus>late</stepStatus>
              <background-color>#ea002a</background-color>
              <border-color>#B70000</border-color>
              <color>#ffffff</color>
            </PreRequestChangeStatus>
            <PreRequestChangeStatus diffgr:id="PreRequestChangeStatus3" msdata:rowOrder="2" diffgr:hasChanges="inserted">
              <company>1</company>
              <version>1</version>
              <changeID>208</changeID>
              <stageID>2</stageID>
              <status>late</status>
              <stepID>6</stepID>
              <stepStatus>off</stepStatus>
              <background-color>#bbbbbb</background-color>
              <border-color>#888888</border-color>
              <color>#222222</color>
            </PreRequestChangeStatus>
            <PreRequestChangeStatus diffgr:id="PreRequestChangeStatus4" msdata:rowOrder="3" diffgr:hasChanges="inserted">
              <company>1</company>
              <version>1</version>
              <changeID>208</changeID>
              <stageID>2</stageID>
              <status>late</status>
              <stepID>7</stepID>
              <stepStatus>off</stepStatus>
              <background-color>#bbbbbb</background-color>
              <border-color>#888888</border-color>
              <color>#222222</color>
            </PreRequestChangeStatus>
            <PreRequestChangeStatus diffgr:id="PreRequestChangeStatus5" msdata:rowOrder="4" diffgr:hasChanges="inserted">
              <company>1</company>
              <version>1</version>
              <changeID>208</changeID>
              <stageID>2</stageID>
              <status>late</status>
              <stepID>8</stepID>
              <stepStatus>late forecast-past</stepStatus>
              <background-color>#ea002a</background-color>
              <border-color>#0033a1</border-color>
              <color>#ffffff</color>
            </PreRequestChangeStatus>
          </PreRequestChangeStatus>
        </diffgr:diffgram>
      </GetStatusForPreRequestChangeDTResult>
    </GetStatusForPreRequestChangeDTResponse>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

However no matter how I set up the code in SSRS, I only get the metadata back, or a blank dataset:

When I code:

```
<Query>
<Method  Name="GetStatusForPreRequestChangeDT" Namespace="http://tempuri.org/">
</Method>
<SoapAction>http://tempuri.org/IChangeTool/GetStatusForPreRequestChangeDT</SoapAction>
</Query>
```

I get only the metadata:
[image: MetaData]

When I code:

```
<Query>
<Method  Name="GetStatusForPreRequestChangeDT" Namespace="http://tempuri.org/">
</Method>
<SoapAction>http://tempuri.org/IChangeTool/GetStatusForPreRequestChangeDT</SoapAction>
<ElementPath IgnoreNamespaces="true">GetStatusForPreRequestChangeDTResponse{}/GetStatusForPreRequestChangeDTResult{}/diffgram{}/PreRequestChangeStatus{}/name{company, version, changeID, stageID, stepID, stepStatus, background-color, border-color, color}</ElementPath>
</Query>
```

I get a blank dataset:
[image]

I know this is lengthy but HOW do I dig below the metadata and let the details populate?
~James

Comment: does `<ElementPath IgnoreNamespaces="true">*</ElementPath>` also give you blank dataset?

Comment: Abhishek, I had tried that and it also returns the metadata dataset.